# Can I use “Time” as an independent variable in my model in a Machine Learning problem?

Tags: machine-learning, python, predictive-models

I am a new user of Python and Machine learning!

Hereunder, I am trying to explain my data and model and then ask my question.

I have a couple of **independent variables**: Ambient temperature, Solar intensity, PCM melting temperature (*PCM is a kind of material that we glue to the back of the PV panel in this experiment*) and, Wind speed. My only **dependent variable** is the power output of a photovoltaic panel.

All independent variables change during a day (from 8 AM to 5 PM) as "Time" passes. For instance, ambient temperature increases from 8 AM to 3 PM and gradually drops from 3 PM to 5 PM.

**My question is**: can I consider "Time" (which is defined in an hour -- e.g. 8,9,....,13,14,....,17) as another independent variable to use machine learning techniques (in Python) like linear regression, Bayesian linear regression and SVM in order to predict the behaviour of the system?

I think because time here shows its effects on temperatures and solar intensity directly, I can disregard "time" as another independent variable.

I am quite confused here. Any help and suggestion would be much appreciated.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You may wish to read about [tag:time-series] analysis, which is a large topic in statistics and machine learning.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will.

Comment: Yes, time series analysis.  All of your measurements are correlated, since they are from the same PV -- over time.

Comment: Thank you.

For example, I know how to code for linear regression or SVM (if I consider TIME as another independent variable), but do you know if I want to change the code to a time series analysis code, what should I do? I don't know how to code to get a time series analysis in python. I need to compare three machine learning algorithms: Linear regression, Bayesian linear regression and SVM.